# Rails enums preventing destroy actions in PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a whole bunch of enums in my application where I use a hash to define the enums like so:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  enum eventable_type: { comment: 0, review: 1, track: 2, follow: 3, unfollow: 4, 
                        favorite: 5, unfavorite: 6, purchase: 7, blog: 8,
                        listing: 9, album: 10, pseudonym: 11, topic: 12, notation: 13,
                        wiki: 14, like: 15, dislike: 16}
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now in my other models, for example the Track model, I have something like this:

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :events, as: :eventable, dependent: :destroy
```

The enums work great until I need to destroy a Track. If I try to do it in the rails console, the problem arises when the PG database tried to destroy the events associated with the Track first.

```
Event Destroy (1.8ms) DELETE FROM "events" WHERE "events"."eventable_id" = $1 AND "events"."eventable_type" = $2 [["eventable_id", 10], ["eventable_type", "Track"]]
TRANSACTION (1.1ms) ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from (irb):3
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "Track")
```

I was hoping it would just work, as many of the rails tutorials say to set up enums this way.

Rails version:
Rails 6.1.0.alpha

Ruby version:
ruby 2.6.0p0

How do I get PG to use the integer value instead of the string part of the enum? Is there a way to make it work without migrating all my tables to have a new PG enum setup? I could do that, but then I would have to figure out how to change every record in the database to reflect the new values.

Comment: [This article](https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum) describes the problem you are seeing and a method to avoid it. Look at Section 2 of the article.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping to avoid. I would have to redo all the tables to switch to the new PG enum, that part is totally doable. The problem lies in now having a whole bunch of records that currently exist in my database that I would have to manually update each one, as they all currently have integers (i.e. every comment, event, flag, etc.). I was hoping there was a different way. Thank you for the article link. If I can't find a workaround, that is the way I will go.

Comment: Sometimes data migrations happen. :) Not sure what you mean by "manually," but you ought to be able to make a new column and write a bit of Ruby or SQL to update everything in pretty short order.

Comment: Well I meant like each comment has a commentable_type enum. If I dropped that current column in the db to create the new one that uses a string instead, I will have to look at each comment and set its commentable_type for example, yes? Then I would have to do that same thing with every other thing that uses enums currently.

Comment: I would make a new column called something like `temp_commentable_type`, then migrate the data, then delete the old column, then rename `temp_commentable_type` to `commentable_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by foregoing the enum values for the _types (commentable_type, eventable_type, etc.) by changing them from integers to strings. First, I made a migration to add a new column to the database while renaming the old columns so I could easily migrate the data afterwards.

```
class ChangeFromEnumIntegersToStrings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    rename_column :events, :eventable_type, :eventable_type_old
    rename_column :flags, :flaggable_type, :flaggable_type_old
    rename_column :flags, :flag_type, :flag_type_old
    rename_column :notifications, :commentable_type, :commentable_type_old
    rename_column :notifications, :notifiable_type, :notifiable_type_old
    add_column :events, :eventable_type, :string
    add_column :flags, :flaggable_type, :string
    add_column :flags, :flag_type, :string
    add_column :notifications, :commentable_type, :string 
    add_column :notifications, :notifiable_type, :string 
  end
end
```

Once I migrated the database, I then went into the rails console and just changed all the records like so for each of the old enum values.

```
Notification.where(:notifiable_type_old => 0).update_all("notifiable_type = 'comment'")
```